# How to remove pending App icons from my iphone?

Tags: ios, ios7, code-signing-certificate

We have a situation here.. we have an internal app store and we install apps internally from this only.
The apps we deploy to this are signed by distribution certs but i had an issue in the PLIST so these apps while installing were producing another icon which is the succesfully loaded app but the initial icon just stays there trying to install. When i try to these pending icons it doesn't get deleted.

Anyone has come across a similar issue ?? If yes how should i remove those from my device?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried restarting the device?

Comment: Yup. Didn't work. Also i tried it with Organizer,iTunes and iPhone Configuration utility but they are not showing this app at all. so there is no way to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Apps stuck on pending updates:

- Tap **Settings**
- Tap **General**
- Tap **Storage & iCloud**
- Under the Storage section, tap **Manage Storage**
- Scroll through the app list and tap on the app you want to delete
- Now tap the **Delete App** button
- Again reinstall that App from App store